# Limit NSAttributedString number of lines

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, nsparagraphstyle

is there a way to limit number of lines in paragraph in **NSAttributedString**?
Im appending two strings in **NSAttributedString** and i want them to be maximum 3 lines, the first string will be 1-2 lines , truncated if needed. and the second string should be always on the last line
Something like:

```
this is my first string
if its too long i't will get trun...
But this is my second string
```

what i did is:

```
    // First string
    NSAttributedString *first = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"this is my first string if its too long i't will get trunticated"
                                                               attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                                                                            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.0]];
    [str appendAttributedString:first];

    // New line
    [str appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];

    // Add photo count
    NSAttributedString *second = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"But this is my second string"
                                                                attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                                                                             NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0]}];
    [str appendAttributedString:second];
```

But the result is:

```
this is my first string
if its too long i't will get
trunticated
```

The first string takes the first 3 lines and push the second string out of the label.
How can i limit the first string paragraph to 2 lines?

Comment: have you been able to solve this yet?

Comment: Nop... for now i just use two different labels

Comment: is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can count the amount of letters that your graphic component (UITextView or UITextField) can handle using uppercase and bigger width ones repeatedly to see this. Than, use:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{}
```

to check every input, if the amount is enough, or if it stills available for more letters. Create a character limit and decrease it everytime this  method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the number of lines with one constraint !

Simply add a NSLayoutConstraint on your UILabel with following values :

- attribute = NSLayoutAttributeHeight ('Height' in Storyboard)
- relation = NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual ('Less Than or Equal' in Storyboard)
- constant = height-for-number-of-lines-you-want

See Storyboard integration :

[image: See storyboard integration]